# graphics::locator() function cannot be used inside shiny?

Tags: r, shiny, graphics, shinydashboard

It seems like the graphics::locator() function can not be used inside a shiny app, anyone knows why it behaviors like that? The output of the function is displayed at the normal plot tab in RStudio, it does not show inside your app.

Comment: You are correct that `graphics::locator` cannot be used on shiny apps. Buy what exactly is your requirement? There are existing examples of interactive shiny plots available at https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/plot-interaction.html. Would one o those techniques work for you?

Comment: Very likely you don't need `locator`. Take a look at `?plotOutput` and you will see that shiny can make available to the server the location of where user hovers, brushes, clicks or double-clicks on a plot.

Comment: Indeed, i am using the plot interaction features available in shiny to create an app that measures the distance between 2 clicks. I just couldn't find the reason why locator does not work, since imo its an easier solution.